# Pycharm issue - ImportError: No module named appengine.datastore.datastore_query

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pycharm

I have been trying to use the excellent project located at http://docs.gae-init.appspot.com/, in order to learn python, GAE and perhaps start my own hobby project.
My IDE of choice is Pycharm 3.4 Professional Edition. Operating system is OSX Mavericks.

I have been trying to follow the tutorial, therefore I have git cloned the project at a local directory and subsequently opened in into Pycharm. I believe I have managed to resolve the majority of requirements (PyCharm helps a lot).

Nevertheless, when trying to Run the project I get the following error:

```
  File "/Users/nilminus/Developer/phonebook/main/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    import util
  File "/Users/nilminus/Developer/phonebook/main/util.py", line 10, in <module>
    from google.appengine.datastore.datastore_query import Cursor
ImportError: No module named appengine.datastore.datastore_query
```

I have configured GAE directory as /usr/local/google_appengine which is correct.
Pycharm does not complain about not finding this module before actually executing it.
There is a warning that module google is not listed in requirements.txt, but it does not makes sense to me that this could be the issue.

I have included PYTHONPATH in .profile and ~/.bash_profile:
PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/google_appengine/:/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/:/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/yaml/

The funny thing is that if I upload this exact project in GAE, it works perfectly.
Also, if I run this project with ./run.py -s (as exhibited by its author), it works again.
Even ./dev_appserver.py main/ works.

This issue has truely dazzled me that last week.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When creating Google Engine App project, specify App Engine SDK path in App Engine SDK directory field:

[image: App Engine Project Settings]

Note:  PyCharm automatically detects the GAE installation path, and displays it in this field. However,  Auto-detection works for Windows and OS X. For Linux, you have to specify the App Engine SDK yourself.

Also specify SDK path in Settings [image: App Engine Path]

Comment: I have not created a new GAE project. I have opened the directory with Pycharm and then in Preferences, I have added GAE support. I don't see how its possible to create a new project with existing source code.

Comment: Using Pycharm create a new empty App Engine project, copy .idea directory (this directory is hidden) from this new project to your above mentioned project.